# JAX-RS: PUT/POST with JSON array does not deserialize as typed list

Tags: java, json, rest, jackson, jax-rs

I'm trying to PUT a JSON array to a JAX-RS service (using Jackson as JSON provider). The service is declared as follows:

```
@PUT
public Response setList(List<MyPojo> pojoList) {
    ...
}
```

When the method is called, the members of `pojoList` are of type `LinkedHashMap` instead of `MyPojo`. So Jackson deserializes the list as a general "list of maps" instead of using the declared type.

I know that Jackson is able to deserialize typed lists when using its `ObjectMapper` directly. But how can tell Jackson to do this when using it via JAX-RS? Is there a special `@Json...` annotation for this that I'm missing?

Comment: Show use the relevant code of `MyPojo`. Are you using JAXB annotations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just discovered that this is a side effect of using CDI Interceptors (at least when using WELD as CDI provider). The proxy class used by the CDI interceptors destroys the Generics information of method parameters.

So the CDI proxy causes

```
public Response setList(List<MyPojo> pojoList) {
    ...
}
```

to appear as

```
public Response setList(List pojoList) {
    ...
}
```

to Resteasy (= our JAX-RS provider). Therefore it is deserialized as a "list of maps" by Jackson. Removing the Interceptor solves the issue, but unfortunately that's not a feasible option for us.